# Cost of key duplication

Tags: sql

I have an address book stored in SQL (OK, the truth is that I have something more complicated than an address book, but my question works for an address book :)). It maps a name to a phone number. For the sake of the discussion, let's say that we are using fixed size fields and that a line occupies 100 bytes on disk.
Now, I find myself needing multiple address books, one per user of my application. Users are identified by a 16 byte GUID. I think I should add a column to the "address book" table, so that I have "UserID, Name, PhoneNumber".
I care about the size of the database on disk, and I believe adding the UerID column will increase the size of the DB by 16%. For a single user, this seems stupid (having the same UserID repeated on every row of the DB).

Does a typical SQL implementation do anything to avoid the cost of repeating the same value on multiple rows in a table?
Is there a better way to layout the data to avoid that cost?

Comment: is there any specific reason you are using GUID as a Primary Key for your users, It is one of the worst data types for a Primary Key (For performance reasons). Why not use INT , 4 bytes , 4 times less space than GUID 4 times less work for SQL Server to maintain an INT column then it would have done to maintain a GUID Column. Also GUID Primary key will result in excessive page splits ,,,,, not good not at all :)

Comment: this also depends on the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ..).

Comment: @M.Ali: It is requires 2 queries for every insert to get the PK.

Comment: There are reasons why the ID needs to be a GUID in my particular case, but even if it were an int, I still feel dumb to add that int to every row in the DB. In C++ say, I would have expected to go from map<string, phoneNumber> to map<UserID, map<string, phoneNumber>>, which would have basically zero overhead for the single user case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about storage on disk.  Alas, that depends on the database.  In general, databases are going to store the GUID using 16 bytes.  If the GUID were a string, then some databases might do some sort of "compression" on a page where repeated values are stored only once.  Columnar databases would probably do this compression for any time of value.  You don't specify the database you are using, so one of these might apply.

The amount of space that a table takes on disk is probably irrelevant to your needs.  Most databases pre-allocate table spaces for tables.  The space is divided into pages and there are lots of unused pages in a table space.  One of the key things that databases do is manage this memory hierarchy.  I wouldn't worry about an additional 16 bytes per record.  Well, I might if the additional data were a set of flags that fit into 1 or 2 bytes and I had tens of millions of records.  Then the overhead would be a lot.  Although there are SQL engines that use a model where each table is in a separate file (MS Access), there are plenty of more powerful free engines (MySQL, SQLite, Postgres, SQL Server Express, Oracle Express, and no doubt others).

If, for some reason, you really do care about the physical usage of disk space, I would recommend a columnar database such a ParAccel or Vertica.

For an internal database structure, integer keys are usually recommended.  They are more efficient for joins and they take up less space.  If you have multiple address books per user, then I would suggest that you break up your single table into two tables:  `Users` and `UserAddressBooks`.  The first would have an auto-incremented id column stored as an integer.  The second would have this id as a column along with the additional information you want.  I would recommend this a little bit for performance but more because it's a better  implementation of the logical data model.